# How to get top 20 CPU user in the cluster

Tags: shell, resources, cpu-usage

I need to get a report for top 20 cpu users in a cluster collectively (not individual node) (rhel 6.x).

For Ex: I have 100 nodes, I need a report which will provide me what all top 20 users utilized the CPU resources in the cluster.

Thanks in advance

Comment: So, you want a code to do this job? Please elaborate question.

Comment: hello @Ajay2588 A code or open source utility whichever can provide me solution.

Comment: You suppose to write a script to perform the check [top 20 CPU users]. Top 20 CPU users per day/second/minute etc....